# extracting facebook token from url and processing in form

Tags: php, javascript

My facebook application generates a url like this when authenticated

I need to use regex to extract the part between = and &

> `http://mydomain.com/token.php#access_token=CAACZCwCGi5JABAFKTYg7X4g7N5eq0Npc6d9kFjn8LNhYdXAGBasbrAStsdRzDg7lQ2OCwhWZCNP73k5uGj6rtGh5ZBHPv3MniE74zYWgq7ls2tQaXFyOY1dhyQdBVm67Ok6Q1y32cUHTHCZAOeU7WZBSmaDksdfkZD&expires_in=5181223&code=AQDNbbH2cvM2pvjOO-P2luM8atGhhqlGDQDnpHteR3KiJ7DmuusFwfvnJgpr4xMph4z-xlQ52PaAIG4FjVKfdXiYm4rbHdTBIuGmKkGleoZUIuiETFNRKA5rOJaseoTod-n1wXg913LqJEupWt0dv0i_45pQlefrRiCFC8JCmcAZJOjz2Lwbt1pyHoxY7VCGoi7umlfeVN9OBs6tYpV97zO9h9fzNsLbpQSyY9k8veFR50Rfx7zCQBZKgIilcyQGe7x7mtbQfFMtQzqUnobmuuDnOTBiOL7mM028LS16sx4XIhYaqbPc1KBy5aZ-oe1dtpA`

we'll call this variable $token

mydomain.com/token.php also has the following form to use the token:

```
<form action="http://domain.com/run.php" method="post" id="form1">
<input type="hidden"  name="token" value="<php echo $token; ?>" /></form>
<script language="JavaScript"> 
    document.getElementById('form1').submit();</script>
```

$token is used on a 2nd page (run.php)

how do I

1. extract the token with regex
2. echo the $token variable in the second page (run.php)

Answer (score 1):

Does this helps ?

```
/\b(access_token=)(\w)*\b/gi
```

To echo the submitted post value, just $_POST["token"].

Comment: how do i put /\b(access_token=)(\w)*\b/gi in a php script?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://mydomain.com/token.php#access_token=CAACZCwCGi5JABAFKTYg7X4g7N5eq0Npc6d9kFjn8LNhYdXAGBasbrAStsdRzDg7lQ2OCwhWZCNP73k5uGj6rtGh5ZBHPv3MniE74zYWgq7ls2tQaXFyOY1dhyQdBVm67Ok6Q1y32cUHTHCZAOeU7WZBSmaDksdfkZD&expires_in=5181223&code=AQDNbbH2cvM2pvjOO-P2luM8atGhhqlGDQDnpHteR3KiJ7DmuusFwfvnJgpr4xMph4z-xlQ52PaAIG4FjVKfdXiYm4rbHdTBIuGmKkGleoZUIuiETFNRKA5rOJaseoTod-n1wXg913LqJEupWt0dv0i_45pQlefrRiCFC8JCmcAZJOjz2Lwbt1pyHoxY7VCGoi7umlfeVN9OBs6tYpV97zO9h9fzNsLbpQSyY9k8veFR50Rfx7zCQBZKgIilcyQGe7x7mtbQfFMtQzqUnobmuuDnOTBiOL7mM028LS16sx4XIhYaqbPc1KBy5aZ-oe1dtpA';
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT), $params);
?>

<form action="http://domain.com/run.php" method="post" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden"  name="token" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($params['access_token']) ?>" /></form>
</form>
<script type= text/javascript>
    document.getElementById('form1').submit();
</script>
```

You can use this token in run.php via `$_POST['token']` (See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

### Docs:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php